# Exception while copying data to AWS S3

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Requirement**

1. To create a stored procedure for copying to AWS S3.
2. To generate a filename with current date

What I have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_S3_COPY("ENV" VARCHAR(16777216), "SCHEMA_ENV" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
    var return_rows = [];
    var GET_CURRENT_DATE = `SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE()::VARCHAR,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MMDDYYYY')`;
 
    var COPY_TO_S3 = `COPY INTO ''s3://bucket/dev/file_${GET_CURRENT_DATE}.csv'' FROM my_schema.my_table
                        CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID=''aws_key'' AWS_SECRET_KEY=''aws_secret'')
                        FILE_FORMAT = my_csv_file_format
                        HEADER=TRUE
                        single=true
                        max_file_size=4900000000;`;
    
    try {           
            /* Get the current date in specific format */
            snowflake.execute ({sqlText: GET_CURRENT_DATE}); 
            
            /* Copy to AWS S3 and fetch the number of rows copied */
            var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: COPY_TO_S3}); 
            result.next();
            return_rows.push(result.getColumnValue(1))
            return return_rows;
        }
    catch (err)  {
            throw `Exception/Error occured in procedure PROC_S3_COPY: "${err}"`;         
        }
$$
```

This is the exception I get when I executed this procedure:

> syntax error line 1 at position 12 unexpected 's3://bucket/dev/file_SELECT'." in PROC_S3_COPY at '            throw `Exception/Error occured in procedure PROC_S3_COPY: "${err}"`;         ' position 12
>
> Stackstrace:
>
> PROC_S3_COPY line: 23

I think the issue is, when generating the file name with current date, the select statement of current date is getting appended to the copy into query instead of date. My need is push a file named `file_04232023` to my AWS S3. When I manually run the COPY INTO command with hard-coded date, it is successfully uploading to AWS S3.

Kindly extend your help. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You would need to execute the GET_CURRENT_DATE sql and process the result to get the date and then append that to the COPY statement. However, it’s probably easier to just use javascript code to get the current date, rather than SQL

Comment: That is what I'm doing. `snowflake.execute ({sqlText: GET_CURRENT_DATE});` is used in the stored proc first to get the date and then the result is used dynamically when executing the COPY INTO query.

Comment: No it’s not what you are doing, when you run snowflake.execute ({sqlText: GET_CURRENT_DATE}) you aren’t doing anything with the result. You need to do something like var result = snowflake.execute ({sqlText: GET_CURRENT_DATE}); var curr_date = result.next(); You would then build your COPY_TO_S3 string using the curr_date value and then execute it

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it makes sense to generate the current date in Javascript. Try to build your copy command as follows:

```
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const year = currentDate.getFullYear().toString();
    const month = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const day = currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

    const GET_CURRENT_DATE = `${month}${day}${year}`;
 
    var COPY_TO_S3 = `COPY INTO ''s3://bucket/dev/file_${GET_CURRENT_DATE}.csv'' FROM my_schema.my_table
                        CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID=''aws_key'' AWS_SECRET_KEY=''aws_secret'')
                        FILE_FORMAT = my_csv_file_format
                        HEADER=TRUE
                        single=true
                        max_file_size=4900000000;`;
```